# Google Play Console: Delete build from Internal Testing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

As a premise, I have an Android app submitted on Google Play.

I recently found myself submitting a build for Internal Testing (in Google Play Console) which I would now need to delete.

Is it possible, given this build it's on Internal Testing alone and it's the latest submitted, or the only way to go is by submitting a new build with an increased number?

*Thank you!*

Comment: You cannot delete any artefact once uploaded, although you can either push that version to closed/alpha/production or upload a new version by increasing the version number.

Comment: By pushing it to closed testing, would that perhaps allow to re-upload the version with the same build number? Grasping on that final hope, although I'd imagine it's just not possible

Comment: If by `build-number` you refer to the `versionCode` then No, you cannot upload a build with same version code. Version name would not really matter here.

Answer (score 2):

The only way for the internal testing build to be somewhat deactivated but not fully deactivated is to upload a new version with an incremented version code to the internal testing section. If the problem would affect your status with your account or should not be released at all, this is the only way I'm afraid. It used to be possible, but now Google stores all artifacts uploaded to them.